# Fill.in the two missing terms in this Simple Sequence

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, no-computers

What are the two missing numbers in the sequence shown below:

$$\def\S{\phantom{XX}}
\large\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\S&\S&\S&\S&\S&\S\\[-10px]
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
51 & 42 & ? & 84 & 36 & ?
\\[-10px]\\\hline\end{array}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the answer is

> $53$ and $08$.

Because

> If you look at the bottom part and swap the digits, you will get: $15-24-?-48-63-?$

And to solve this

> Look at the differences. The differences are $9-(11)-(13)-15-(17)$ so the question marks will be $35$ and $80$ thus swap the digits again to get the final answer.

Alternatively from @hexomino

> The number below is the digit-reversal of "the square of the number above then minus $1$".

Comment: rot13(Zber pbapvfryl, jr'er erirefvat gur qvtvgf bs $n^2-1$ jurer $n$ vf gur ahzore ba gbc)

Comment: Got it!!…………...

Comment: @hexomino great observation! :o